# Avi networks - AWS policies for controller

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, devops, operations

We are using Avi networks in AWS and I have set up a controller instance with liberal (Admin) policies.

I would like to clamp down on the permissions afforded to this controller instance by it's role. Which policies should I assign to this role?

Ideally I would like a list of functions that the Avi controller is able to preform, along with the corresponding policies that allow these functions. That way I could also tailor the policies to only the functions on the controller that we wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IAM roles to restrict access.

This is documented [here](https://kb.avinetworks.com/docs/latest/iam-role-setup-for-installation-into-aws/)